# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted (only one page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, session-variables

My question may be duplicate. But, I tried others answers but can't solve my problem. My website is run in localhost. When running morning I can see webpage but in evening only one link occurs error. I attach error image in my question ..I store two session variables stored datasets in this page. But not clear after logout.!

[image]

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973838/state-information-corrupted-after-dynamically-adding-control